# Making a div Droppable for file Upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dropzone

I Have Created a div for showing the input image and the output image produced based on the Process that I am gonna do further.

I am able to upload a file simply using submit button and able to get the desired result.
Now as per demand I want the **input image** div to be droppable, Means user can easily drop image into the box and then submit the button for further process. I am not getting the Idea how can I do that .

Here is my HTML code :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <h2 class="inputImage-text text-center">Input Image</h2>

 <form id="uploadForm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div id="targetLayer" class="dropzone dz-clickable dz-default dz-message">No Image</div>
       <div id="uploadFormLayer">
       <input name="fileToUpload" type="file" class="inputFile" /><br/>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
       </div>
       </form>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
       <h2 class="outputImage-text text-center">Output Image</h2>
      <div class="outputDiv">
     </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and Here is my project looks like.
[image]
as you can see I just want the **input image box** to be droppable.
and rest of the process should be same.

If You have any suggestion . please help.

Comment: this may is what you looking for https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/drag-drop-file-uploader-vanilla-js/

Comment: its quite complicated I think. @bobibobi

Comment: then use some js plugin like https://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: I tried . but I also want that When I upload the image on the box. the same value should be gone to the browse section . so that I can process that Value in the next page. image shown in the drop zone. but no further process is going on.

Comment: you can set session for this value to use in every page and unset session when you dont need it anymore